# Burninate [syntax] and [syntax-error]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [syntax](/questions/tagged/syntax) tag has 8500 questions linked to it. A quick glance at the first few pages reinforce the assumption that this is really just about syntax issues.

This tag serves just as much use as tagging a question as 'language' in a linguistics forum. Syntax is what a language consists of: it will likely never be relevant to the question in the way that it adds more value than the specific language tag.

Likewise there is the [syntax-error](/questions/tagged/syntax-error) tag. This one has 2400 questions and is just as useful as the previous one.

A high reputation in a tag should indicate you are knowledgeable in the subject. I don't expect someone to put 'Serious knowledge about syntax' in his resumé.

Therefore I propose both tags to be removed: no question should be any less clear with the removal of the tag.

Comment: Any idea how many of the tagged questions are typo related? (Also, yes, burninate)

Comment: I would estimate about 10% of the questions, give or take a few. The tag is so general is it used in many types of questions, often asking how to do something.

Comment: I've come across higher rep users adding [tag:syntax-error] to questions that they should be closing before, it's definitely a magnet for things that should not be. This means that I'm not certain a burnination is in order without a significant clean-up first.

Comment: Is this significantly different than the [grammar] tag on the English Language and Usage site?